# Logging correlation id per route in Flask

Tags: python, flask, logging, microservices

I'm new to flask and want to read a custom correlation Id from the request and log it for tracing capabilities per route.
I have used similarly capable libraries in [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-correlation-id) and implementations in Java through `HandlerInterceptor` and setting extracted header values in MDC

I see some flask related python libraries but they're implemented in a way to read pre-defined header names rather than allowing custom header names and enabling logging it across the full request life cycle

Any suggestion on reading and logging request header values and setting some unique Id in the response using Flask application

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to answer this question

Register your logger before the request

```
@app.before_request
def init_req():
    g.logger = create_logger("req-"+str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

use the `g.logger` to write your logger

Create logger function can be like this

```
def create_logger(name: str):
    return logging.getLogger(name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally found the answer [here](http://blog.mcpolemic.com/2016/01/18/adding-request-ids-to-flask.html). We can use `flask.g` and the concept of `logging.config` and filters, since I have configured the whole application through common logging.config and patterns. Also, I needed to even read the correlation id through a custom request header let's say `Correlation-ID` or and if not found creating a unique id, so did some changes around that aspect as well.